# How to change UITableViewController (Grouped) text color?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, uitableview

Quick question:

How can i change the label text color of the section i have in a UITableViewController, grouped style?
EDIT:

Example

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{


    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return @"A";
            break;
        case 1:
            return @"B";
            break;
        case 2:
            return @"C";
            break;
        default:
            return nil;
            break;


    }
   }
```

I want "A", "B", "C", to be white. Suggestions?

Comment: which do you want to change ? The cell color or section label color or the color of the rows ?

Comment: Edited the main question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can edit your title color / size of your section. This was mentioned in the apple forums.

What you can do is - Implement your own label / view for the section headers.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// create the parent view that will hold header Label
UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0)];

// create the button object
UILabel * headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
headerLabel.opaque = NO;
headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
headerLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0);

// If you want to align the header text as centered
// headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(150.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0);

headerLabel.text = @" Section Title";
[customView addSubview:headerLabel];

return customView;
}
```

Comment: It kinda works. I mean, if i have to rename multiple Section title should i do a Switch? In your code the headerLabel is almost inside the cells, though

Comment: You can customize the frame size. that is not a problem. And for sections title, you can use a switch or an if-else statement.. `if (indexPath.section == 0) //create label 1    if (indexPath.section ==1) // Create Label 2`

Comment: OK Solution found. thanks for your post, i had to add heightForHeaderInSection in order to display properly the labels. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Oh yes, that was my next suggestion ;) Glad it worked out well for you.